# How to detach size jitter and pen pressure in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to control only the **opacity** and **flow** with my pen pressure, and want to remain brush size constant through out the brush stroke. I have turned on Opacity Jitter and Flow Jitter from Transfer tab in brush pallet and all other options are tuned off. But, still I am getting size jitter.

Why this is happening?

[image]

I am using Photoshop CS4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer from @joeparis from [conceptart.org](http://www.conceptart.org/forums/showthread.php?p=3461955#post3461955) :

Make sure you haven't enabled the "Override" button. If you select this then your tablet/pen controls size.

[image]

Comment: This solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for this. A while back my tablet's pen pressure stopped working and I assumed it was the hardware. Turns out I must have accidentally flipped that switch.

Comment: @johannes In fact whenever I face this issue, I first try with restarting PS followed by detaching the hardware. Sometimes these solves this issue.